# Where can I find the VMware vSphere client?

Tags: download, esxi

VMware's download site is very frustrating. I am unable to find where the download link to the vSphere *client* is.

Did they rename this tool? How can I get it?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I [found someone's blog](http://chall32.blogspot.com/2011/10/vmware-vsphere-client-download-url.html) who had the same problem. He points to hardcoded links to VMware's clients:
(And [another blog](http://www.josephturley.com/vsphere-5-5-client-download/))

#### vSphere v6.0

- VMware vSphere Client v6.0: [VMware-viclient-all-6.0.0-2502222.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/2/5/0/2/2/2/2/VMware-viclient-all-6.0.0-2502222.exe)

#### vSphere v5.5

- VMware vSphere Client v5.5.0: [VMware-viclient-all-5.5.0-1281650.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/1/2/8/1/6/5/0/VMware-viclient-all-5.5.0-1281650.exe)
- Download vSphere Client 5.5 Update 1: [VMware-viclient-all-5.5.0-1618071.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/1/6/1/8/0/7/1/VMware-viclient-all-5.5.0-1618071.exe)
- Download vSphere Client 5.5 Update 1b: [VMware-viclient-all-5.5.0-1880841.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/1/8/8/0/8/4/1/VMware-viclient-all-5.5.0-1880841.exe)
- Download vSphere Client 5.5 Update 2: [VMware-viclient-all-5.5.0-1993072.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/1/9/9/3/0/7/2/VMware-viclient-all-5.5.0-1993072.exe)

#### vSphere v5.1

- VMware vSphere Client v5.1:  [VMware-viclient-all-5.1.0-786111.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/7/8/6/1/1/1/VMware-viclient-all-5.1.0-786111.exe)
- VMware vSphere Client 5.1.0a: [VMware-viclient-all-5.1.0-860230.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/8/6/0/2/3/0/VMware-viclient-all-5.1.0-860230.exe)  (seems to be not available 7-17-2014)
- VMware vSphere Client 5.1.0b: [VMware-viclient-all-5.1.0-941893.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/9/4/1/8/9/3/VMware-viclient-all-5.1.0-941893.exe)
- VMware vSphere Client 5.1 Update 1: [VMware-viclient-all-5.1.0-1064113.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/1/0/6/4/1/1/3/VMware-viclient-all-5.1.0-1064113.exe)
- VMware vSphere Client 5.1 Update 1: [VMware-viclient-all-5.1.0-1235233.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/1/2/3/5/2/3/3/VMware-viclient-all-5.1.0-1235233.exe)

#### vSphere v5.0

- VMware vSphere Client v5.0:  [VMware-viclient-all-5.0.0-455964.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/4/5/5/9/6/4/VMware-viclient-all-5.0.0-455964.exe)
- VMware vSphere Client v5.0 Update 1: [VMware-viclient-all-5.0.0-623373.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/6/2/3/3/7/3/VMware-viclient-all-5.0.0-623373.exe)
- VMware vSphere Client v5.0 Update 1b: [VMware-viclient-all-5.0.0-804277.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/8/0/4/2/7/7/VMware-viclient-all-5.0.0-804277.exe)
- VMware vSphere Client v5.0 Update 2:  [VMware-viclient-all-5.0.0-913577.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/9/1/3/5/7/7/VMware-viclient-all-5.0.0-913577.exe)

#### vSphere v4.1

- VMware vSphere Client v4.1: [VMware-viclient-all-4.1.0-258902.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/2/5/8/9/0/2/VMware-viclient-all-4.1.0-258902.exe)
- VMware vSphere Client v4.1 Update 1: [VMware-viclient-all-4.1.0-345043.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/3/4/5/0/4/3/VMware-viclient-all-4.1.0-345043.exe)
- VMware vSphere Client v4.1 Update 2: [VMware-viclient-all-4.1.0-491557.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/4/9/1/5/5/7/VMware-viclient-all-4.1.0-491557.exe)
- VMware vSphere Client v4.1 Update 3: [VMware-viclient-all-4.1.0-799345.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/7/9/9/3/4/5/VMware-viclient-all-4.1.0-799345.exe)
- VMware vSphere Client v4.1 Update 3a: [VMware-viclient-all-4.1.0-925676.exe](http://vsphereclient.vmware.com/vsphereclient/9/2/5/6/7/6/VMware-viclient-all-4.1.0-925676.exe)

Comment: This is now outdated, as is the blog.  Mengdi's answer below links to the official VMware KB article.  http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2089791.

Comment: How can a company this big fail so hard on such simple things is beyond me...
PS: The answer of @Mendi is also outdated.

Answer (score 25):

[Download links of all versions of VMware vSphere Clients](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2089791) was officially provided by VMware since 2014-12-15.

Comment: This is the best answer as it points to VMWare official page

Comment: Except the link is dead

Comment: Fix your link or get rid of answer.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/vmware-vsphere-client-install/

If you have installed VMware ESXi server, you can manage the ESXi server using vSphere client. vSphere client works only on Windows host. If you don’t have vSphere client installed, download it from your local VMware Server home page. i.e go to http://{your-vmware-server-ip} to download vSphere client.

Comment: I read this too, however the server has a webserver running so these requests simply get forwarded to apache.  I've downloaded the client direct from them before...I just need to do it again :(

Comment: That should be `http://{your-esx-server-ip}/` and not any of the host's IPs.  There's also a [slightly more canonical reference](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esxi-installable-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.gsinstallable.doc_41/common/install/t_down_client.html).

Comment: That only provides a link directly to the same version as the ESXi host which is likely older than current.  My ESXi host version is incompatible with Windows 8.1 that I was trying to install it on.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the desktop client there is also a [vSphere web client](https://kb.vmware.com/kb/2032890) available (at least since 5.5).

Beware that in the future (past version 6.0) the desktop client might be discontinued and the vSphere web client might become the default to interact with the servers. At least according to this [blog post](https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2016/05/goodbye-vsphere-client-for-windows-c-hello-html5.html) from Dennis Lu who's the product manager for the vSphere web client.