# Which VMware I need for acces to Vmwares hosted in another local Server

Tags: vmware-server

I have **two Virtual machines** virtualized with VMWARE and would like to configure a kind of server with this virtual machines and access to this virtual machines and can made Copy and paste from the remote Vmware Server (vmwares Machines) to the my computer.

Comment: If I'm honest - I have no idea what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You need this [vSphere Client](https://superuser.com/questions/439356/where-can-i-download-vsphere-client), download it and point it at the ESXi client your VM is installed in.

Comment: But with the vSphere Client I cannot install in a Windows 7 Pro or Windows XP ?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot install on win7 or XP, I have run the client on both 7 and XP.

Comment: I have Windows 7 64 bits I have a image with the error http://i46.tinypic.com/a28bb5.png